# Create digital certificate in java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, client-server, x509certificate

I have a client / server program that must do the following:
The client creates a digital certificate and sign it from the server.

I wonder how can I create that certificate in the client (using java)? and then send it to the server (via socket) to sign it.
Then, any client want to communicate with another client, it get its digital certificate and  verify it signed from the server.

Comment: You'd probably have to send the .keystore and .keycert files to your server... I've got no idea why you'd want to do this this way, or why you're talking about using raw sockets vs FTP (unless that's what you meant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keytool utility can be used to generate public and private keypairs and  associated certificate.

Socket class of java.net can be used to send the file through Socket.

[you can find the details about Keytool here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)